# dynamically added form element ids not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form in which a user can click a button and add additional fields as needed.  Later on, user clicks submit, i do some error checking via ajax.  if the additional fields are blank, i want to highlight them in red to let user know its required data.

jquery to add row:

```
  $('#addPerson').click(function(){
  var row = "<div id='row_"+rowNum+"'><div class='leftBigRow'><input type='text' class='field' id='addPerson[name][]' name='addPerson[name][]' placeholder='persons name'></div>";
  $('.additionalPeople').append(row);
  rowNum++;
```

my ajax call returns a string of field ids that have errors.  for example result could be:

```
 //firstname,lastName,zipCode,...etc
```

so my errorcheck is:

```
 if(result.length > 0)
     {
       var errors = result.split(",");
       for (i=1;i<errors.length;i++)
       {
        alert(errors[i]);
        $('#'+errors[i]).addClass('error');
        alert($('#'+errors[i]).val());
       }
       $("#subForm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
```

the first alert returns what i would expect "addPerson[name][0]";
the second alert returns undefined.  telling me it cant find that field....

i have added a fiddle:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Myra4/1/)

in my fiddle var result is a representation of what i get back from the ajax call. my ultimate goal is to get each field added by pressing yes to turn red if blank....

Comment: `var result = ",super,addPerson\\[name\\]\\[\\]";` because `[` & `]` need to be escaped   http://jsfiddle.net/Myra4/2/

Comment: so i can use an array? answer below says i cant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with `id` equal to "addPerson[name][0]". When adding new `input` elements to DOM, you have to include `rowNum` in their `id` and `name` attributes.

Do not include "[" and "]" in name/id attributes. Use:

```
var row = "<div id='row_"+rowNum+"'><div class='leftBigRow'><input type='text' class='field' id='addPerson_name_"+rowNum+"' name='addPerson_name_"+rowNum+"' placeholder='persons name'></div>";
```

Comment: argh, that makes error checking on the other side of the ajax call arduous.  thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your dynamic element's id, you cannot use an array there. You can concatenate it with the `rowNum` count that you already have.

I have updated your JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Myra4/3/

(Observe how I changed the dynamic element's id and your simulated 'result' variable)

*I did it in JSFiddle for you so you can immediately verify that it works.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` to bind later created DOM elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/